# ruby stops after first loop

Tags: firefox, watir

```
for e in 1..43 do
    browser.link(:xpath,".//*[@id='buttonPrint']").click
    sleep 3
    puts browser.link(:xpath,".//*[@id='cmdNext']").click
end


browser.goto "http://www.cramster.com/solution/solution/912984"

for f in 1..33 do
    browser.link(:xpath,".//*[@id='buttonPrint']").click
    sleep 3
    puts browser.link(:xpath,".//*[@id='cmdNext']").click
end
```

i want to have ruby go to the first url, click through all the buttons then go to the second url and click through all the buttons
right now ruby goes to the first url, performs the loop and does not see the second url
?

Comment: it works now, it seems that sometimes it runs through the first loop then stops while other times it goes through both, any thoughts?

Comment: we could help more if you provided link to the page or relevant HTML

Comment: The only stuff you need to see from the cramster site is here http://www.cramster.com/cramster-legal.aspx   see section 6, item G "no robots"

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is in violation of the Cramster terms of service.

> G.    No Bugs, Robots or other Automated
>   Programs. You may not use or introduce
>   bugs, robots or other automated
>   browsing or posting programs on or to
>   the Web Site at any time.

I therefore refuse to assist you and encourage other users to do likewise

Unless you want to come up with some credentials, other than a brand-new stackoverflow user account with no history and no details, and something that shows you are doing this with Cramster's permission  (e.g. a tester working for them) we are done here.

Comment: I had not realized that. Thanks for letting me know. I deleted my comments and posts from this and the other cramster-related question.